# iPhone - core data NSInteger, integer32, int or whatever

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I have a core data value that is "integer 32". How should I set/get values from this?

with

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:X]
```

or with

```
[NSNUmber numberWithInt:X]
```

?

Comment: they are the same???? thanks.

Comment: on 64bits machine NSInteger is long (integer 64), but on iPhone they are same

Comment: Now that iPhone is 64 bit as well, is this answer still the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSInteger` is simply a `typedef` for `int`, so you don't lose/gain integer precision one way or another. Both will work.

Answer (score 8):

As Jack said, it's a typedef.  To add on to the answer, here's how you find out.

In XCode, hold down Apple key with your source file open.  You'll see NSInteger become a link.  After clicking on it, it will open it's definition.

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 ||      NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

Also, xlc0212's point is a good one.  If you read the definition above, it's pretty clear.

Comment: +1 This is one of the most awesome Xcode features ever. So nice for quickly looking at public methods/properties.